# Internet Explorer protected mode error

Tags: .net, selenium, nunit, webdriver

My code in Visual studio is using selenium webdriver 2.24.0.  My testing framework I'm using is Nunit.  My code worked just fine(loading diff. browsers, driving the websites) until version 2.24.0 was released.

I added the new IE standalone server to my project.

Now whenever I run my code NUnit encounters this error message.

```
 FirstSeleniumTest.SeleniumTest.TestGoogle:
SetUp : System.InvalidOperationException : Unexpected error launching Internet Explorer. Protected Mode settings are not the same for all zones. Enable Protected Mode must be set to the same value (enabled or disabled) for all zones. (NoSuchDriver)
TearDown : System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Then Command prompt pops up with this.

```
Started InternetExplorerDriver server (64-bit)
2.24.0.0
Listening on port 50329
```

I disabled protected mode on my IE. Still no luck.

How can I get my code back to proper webdriving?

Comment: Are you sure that protected mode is disabled for _all_ 4 security zones (Internet, Local intranet, Trusted sites, Restricted sites)?

Comment: Protected mode was still enabled on restricted sites.  Thanks for the fix.  Make that an answer, I'll accept

Comment: related: Underlying Selenium Feature Request http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=1795

Comment: @RubenBartelink Not really a feature request, more like the feature is working exactly as it should. See [http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.com/2012/08/youre-doing-it-wrong-protected-mode-and.html](http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.com/2012/08/youre-doing-it-wrong-protected-mode-and.html) for more detail.

Comment: @JimEvans thanks for pointing that out - great detailed article (and great TL;DR summary). Can't say I took the time to properly read my cited article (I synced the settings and got one with life) - I had quickly jumped to my conclusion that the issue was asking for what I wanted at the time - all the drivers to work OOTB in all contexts without needing to understand anything, yes, even with ESC in the picture :D

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should ensure, that protected mode is either enabled or disabled for *all* 4 security zones (Internet, Local intranet, Trusted sites, Restricted sites).
In other words, the setting value should be the same for all security zones.

Comment: Downvoting because the answer implies that Protected Mode must be disabled for all zones. This is incorrect. Protected Mode can be either enabled or disabled, as long as the value is the same for all zones. Correct the answer to **not** imply that Protected Mode _must_ be disabled, and I'll remove the downvote.

Comment: @JimEvans Hey Jim, I don't know why but it only works for me when it's off. Any ideas? I'm on Windows 7 (64-bit) with IE 10.

Answer (score 15):

Just to add to the already correct answers, if setting all values the same is not an option, (Need security disabled is some zones, but want to keep security enabled in others) you can also initialize your driver with the overload that includes `InternetExplorerOptions`, and use

```
new InternetExplorerOptions() { IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to set the Protected Mode settings for each zone to be the same value.
Read: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#Required_Configuration

Answer (score 2):

I Agree with what Alexander is saying but what if your firm does not allow you to make any changes to IE settings.

---

**The following worked for me :**

```
    File file = new File("M:\\dev\\ria\\iedriver\\2.42.0\\install\\exec\\IEDriverServer.exe");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());

    DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
    caps.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);  
    caps.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS,true);

    WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(caps);
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");
```