# Selenium Internet Explorer Driver, Kendo Mobile and Octopus Deploy

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, selenium, kendo-ui, octopus-deploy

We have an MVC 5 C# web application using Kendo Mobile UI compenents which we deploy with Octopus Deploy (Test, Staging, Prod) and have a step to run Selenium UI tests.

The process works perfectly for all environments with the Selenium Chrome driver, however we have an issue with the Selenium Internet Explorer Driver on the servers.

The UI tests fail on the servers when they are run as part of the Octopus Deploy process.
The tests run in local dev, and run on the servers if you execute the script manually (same script and user as the Octopus Deploy process).

The only difference I can see is that one is run headless as part of the tentacle script execution and the other not.

We receive the following error:

> Tentacle script execution
>   OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not displayed

I can recreate this error in local dev by changing the options for the IE web driver to:

```
var options = new InternetExplorerOptions();
options.RequireWindowFocus = false;
var webDriver = new InternetExplorerDriver(options);
```

The element that is causing the problem is a Kendo mobile button:

```
<a data-role="button" data-rel="drawer" id="searchIcon" href="#searchDrawer" data-icon="search" data-align="left"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Tentacle windows service runs under Local System by default, but it doesn't have any UI. 
You'll need to grant the service the ability to interact with the desktop. The following link might be helpful:

http://lostechies.com/keithdahlby/2011/08/13/allowing-a-windows-service-to-interact-with-desktop-without-localsystem/

Comment: This did not work, we have also tried running the tentacle service as an admin user with no luck, when we ran the script manually with the same user it worked fine. Restarted the service after the change to make sure.

Comment: Can you run the Tentacle service interactively (just stop the service, then run Tentacle.exe) to see if that works?

Comment: We followed https://octopusdeploy.com/blog/testing-powershell-scripts to run manually. The first time it ran it failed but all subsequent times it worked. We tried another deployment through the UI but that failed.

Comment: What about running Tentacle interactively (tentacle.exe)?

Comment: Yes it ran successfully interactively

Answer (score 0):

The Protected Mode has to be the same for all zones.
See the answer at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11123960/200824